# Does postgres automatically reindex a table after a new index was created?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with some 670000 records inside it and some indexes.

I created a new index and now I need to know if I have to manually go and reindex that table or Postgres will automatically do that.

Comment: `reindex` will re-create **all** indexes on the table. Why do you think you would need that if you just add a new index?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-reindex.html

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer and it is NO, Postgres does not automatically reindex all the table when you add a new index to it.

Anyway, @a_horse_with_no_name point is good, usually there is no need to reindex all the table when you add a new index to it